# How to style a programatically add element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Could I please ask for help with the following (pictures are not working for me otherwise I would provide screenshots)

Am using Angular.

In my .scss code I have the following style defined:

```
.tableEntryText{
  font-family: Noto Sans;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align:center;
width:50%;
letter-spacing: 0.05px;
color: #1A2321;
}
```

In my html I have a table defined like so:

```
<table id="AssetManagementTable">
    <tr background-color: #F8FAF9; height="56px">
      <th class="tableHeaderText">Tool Series</th>
      <th class="tableHeaderText">Serial Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
      <td class="tableEntryText">3548XA</td>
      <td class="dropdown tableEntryText">
        <form action="" name="FILTER">
            <select class="noBorder" name="filter_for" >
                <option value="374656543">374656543</option>
            </select>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
      <td class="tableEntryText">9878XB</td>
      <td class="dropdown tableEntryText">
        <form action="" name="FILTER">
        <select class="noBorder" name="filter_for" >
            <option value="435454323">435454323</option>
        </select>
    </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

So each "td" element is styled with tableEntryText.

In my component ts code I have a function to add a row to the table:

```
InsertRow(){
    var table = document.getElementById("AssetManagementTable") as HTMLTableElement;

    alert(table.rows[1].cells[0].className);

    var row = table.insertRow() as HTMLTableRowElement;

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML = "XFGF55";
    cell2.innerHTML = "576857463";

    cell1.className = "tableEntryText";
    cell2.className = "tableEntryText";

    alert(table.rows[3].cells[0].className);
  }
```

That alerts are just a test and they show me "tableEntryText" as I would expect. But the new rows generated to not follow that style, I thought they could because of the ".className = ..." lines.

(I have tried using className = ".tableEntryText" in the code but that does not work either).

How can I get programmatically set the style of these new cells to match the existing ones?

(I was trying to avoid doing:

```
ManuallySetStyle(cell)
  {
      cell.style.fontFamily = "Noto Sans";
      cell.style.fontStyle = "normal";
      cell.style.fontWeight = "normal";
      cell.style.fontSize = "14px";
      cell.style.lineHeight = "20px";
      cell.style.textAlign = "center";
      cell.style.width = "50%";
      cell.style.letterSpacing = "0.05px";
      cell.style.color = "#1A2321";
      cell.style.height = "50px";
  }
```

As it duplicates what is in my .scss file. Although it does the job.)

Thanks,

Comment: User, in Angular you should think in "variables". Remember, you has variables in .ts, using this variables you show them or change the  .html. So use a `*ngFor`:https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf. In this way the only you need is an array and add one element to the array

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it made me look harder at the problem and I have now solved it according to your suggested method.

Comment: first, apologies for my comment, I feel that it was not very kindly (sometimes the hurry not let me explain better). I write an answer that I hope can help a bit

Answer (score 0):

User, apologies about my comment. I want to say that in Angular we should think in variables. when we want to repeat something usually we use some like

```
//in .ts
array=[0,1,2]

//in html
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
Hello word
</div>
```

Well, nobody want repeat only "Hello word", so ours arrays usually are array of object

So, some like

```
//in .ts
array=[{name:'jhon'},'name:'peter'}]

//in html
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
{{item.name}}
</div>
```

Show the names "jhon" and "peter".

See your code, see that you're repeating structure, you can think in an array like

```
array=[
       {entryText:'3548XA',options:['374656543']},
       {entryText:'9878XB',options:['435454323']}
]
```

So you can create the .html as

```
<table id="AssetManagementTable">
    <tr background-color: #F8FAF9; height="56px">
      <th class="tableHeaderText">Tool Series</th>
      <th class="tableHeaderText">Serial Number</th>
    </tr>
    <!--see that you iterate over array using *ngFor-->
    <tr *ngFor="let item of array" height="50px">
            <!--as the variable you use to iterate is "item"
                you can "interpolate" and in item.entryText
                you has the value of entryText-->
      <td class="tableEntryText">{{item.entryText}}</td>
      <td class="dropdown tableEntryText">
        <form action="" name="FILTER">
            <select class="noBorder" name="filter_for" >
                <!--here see that you iterate over item.options
                    if you simple want to show the option use {{option}}
                    but in "value" you can use [value]="option"
                    also you can write value="{{option}}" -->
                
                <option *ngFor="let option of item.options" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
            </select>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See that if you want to add a new row, the only is add a new element to the array. You can create a function

```
addElement()
{
   this.array.push({entry:'another',options:['one',two']})
}
```

And call the function in a button, e.g.

```
<button (click)="addElement()">add</button>
```

Yes is a "simple" exercise, but I hope understand me when say that "you should think in "variables"