# ANGULAR 10 Creating dynamically a list of buttons where each button has unique parameter in its onclick event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, onclick

ANGULAR 10: I am stuck for days now. I am working in a code, in an observable event, have code that creates a HTML list, and each item must has a button, so the user can remove each item. I am stuck about creating the onclick event for each button which must remember the "StartDateTime", so when clicked it calls "Remove" function with the correct unique start date & time.

Two problems:

1. It can't find the function to execute, so Angular don't compile it. The function is in another component.
2. How to correctly pass parameter that keep remembered in the HTML button tag?. How to set data for the button, and how to get it later from inside the onclick EVENT?.

Yes, before asking here I tried several examples about how to pass parameters to events (the examples are mainly for JS), but angular didn't like it.

```
 case 'RSV':
        // Param1 = PCNameID.
        // Param2 = StartDate.
        // Param3 = EndDate.
        // Param4 = ReserveByAccountName.
        var node = document.createElement("LI");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("Desde [" + stemp[i].Param2 + "] y hasta [" + stemp[i].Param3 + "] reservado para: " + stemp[i].Param4);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        rsvNode.appendChild(node); 

        var node2 = document.createElement("Button");
        node2.innerText = "Remover esta reserva";

        var SD: string = stemp[i].Param2; // Reserve StartDate.

        node2.onclick ( SD => {
          var StartDate: any;
          StartDate = SD;
          ReservasComponent.RemReserve(StartDate); // Component named ReservasComponent.
        });

        rsvNode.appendChild(node2); 
        break;
```

Comment: You are not doing Angular, you're doing something else. If you find yourself using `document.createElement` or `node.appendChild` you're not doing it right.

Comment: why? it is adding html tags based on what it gets from an API call.

Comment: Angular creates dom by using components and templates. By doing it yourself you are circumventing angular, may as well not use it at all.

Comment: I don't like repeat, but you need "rethink" in variables. See an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443074/how-to-style-a-programatically-add-element-in-angular#comment120990446_68443074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you an example on how you'd do that in Angular.

I see that you have an array with a type field that can be `'RSV'` and for every such item you want a button.

So first, create a filtered array for this:

```js
this.rsvEntries = arr.filter(x => x.type === 'RSV');
```

Next, in your template, create an `ngFor` repeater:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let b of rsvEntries">
  <li>
    Desde [{{b.Param2}}] y hasta [{{b.Param3}}] reservado para: {{b.Param4}}
  </li>
  <button (click)="removeReservation(b)">Remover esta reserva</button>
</ng-container>
```

And finally, in your component create the `removeReservation` method:

```js
removeReservation(rsvEntry) {
  ReservasComponent.RemReserve(rsvEntry.Param2);
}
```

I hope this helps you to get start with proper Angular.